# how to condense multiple jquery if statements

Tags: jquery

Although this works fine , what might be the best way to condense this

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var appointmenttypeval = $('#appointmenttype').val();
  if (appointmenttypeval == "") {
    document.getElementById("appointmenttype").setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  }
  if (appointmenttypeval == "urgent") {
    document.getElementById("appointmenttype").setAttribute("class", "p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white");
  }
  if (appointmenttypeval == "new") {
    document.getElementById("appointmenttype").setAttribute("class", "p-3 mb-2 bg-success text-white");
  }
  if (appointmenttypeval == "followup") {
    document.getElementById("appointmenttype").setAttribute("class", "p-3 mb-2 bg-warning text-dark");
  }
  if (appointmenttypeval == "labs") {
    document.getElementById("appointmenttype").setAttribute("class", "p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white");
  }
});
```

Comment: DRY. At least cache the `document.getElementById("appointmenttype")`

Comment: Then set the BG like this: `{"urgent":"bg-danger","new":"bg-success",...}[appointmenttypeval] || ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object that maps from the appointment type to classes.

```
const appointmentTypes = {
    "": "form-control",
    "urgent": "p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white",
    "new": "p-3 mb-2 bg-success text-white",
    "followup": "p-3 mb-2 bg-warning text-dark",
    "labs": "p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white"
};
$("select").on("change", function() {
    var appointmenttypeval = $('#appointmenttype').val();
    if (appointmenttypeval in appointmentTypes) {
        $("#appointmenttype").attr("class", appointmentTypes[appointmenttypeval]);
    }
});
```

Comment: And cache the element :`const appointmentTypes = { ... };
const $apptype = $('#appointmenttype');
$("select").on("change", function() {
  var val = $apptype.val();
  if (val in appointmentTypes) {
    $apptype.attr("class", appointmentTypes[val]);
  }
});`

Comment: @mplungjan Or use a function argument to `.attr()` that uses `this.value`. It actually went right by me that it was changing the class of the same element it was getting the value of.